# Viewing first 100 floats from binary file

Tags: linux, file, terminal, binary

I have my binary file `base.mod` which is written by C code.It contains 600000 floats.

```
 File: ‘base.mod’
  Size: 2400000     Blocks: 4688       IO Block: 4096   regular file
Device: 801h/2049d  Inode: 3544731     Links: 1
Access: (0664/-rw-rw-r--)  Uid: ( 1000/ milenko)   Gid: ( 1000/ milenko)
Access: 2016-05-05 11:31:33.967649197 -0300
Modify: 2016-05-05 11:31:15.823559225 -0300
Change: 2016-05-05 11:31:15.823559225 -0300
 Birth: -
```

I thought of something like this

```
milenko@milenko-HP-Compaq-6830s:~/Distr70/Pr/Tutorial_Ex3/052$ od -h -N 14400 base.mod
0000000 999a 3f99 999a 3f99 999a 3f99 999a 3f99
*
0034100
```

If I try

```
milenko@milenko-HP-Compaq-6830s:~/Distr70/Pr/Tutorial_Ex3/052$ od -f -N 14400 base.mod
0000000             1,2             1,2             1,2             1,2
*
0034100
```

I would like to get first 100 numbers.
milenko@milenko-HP-Compaq-6830s:~/Distr70/Pr/Tutorial_Ex3/052$ od -f -v -N 400 base.mod

```
0000000             1,2             1,2             1,2             1,2
0000020             1,2             1,2             1,2             1,2
0000040             1,2             1,2             1,2             1,2
0000060             1,2             1,2             1,2             1,2
0000100             1,2             1,2             1,2             1,2
0000120             1,2             1,2             1,2             1,2
0000140             1,2             1,2             1,2             1,2
0000160             1,2             1,2             1,2             1,2
0000200             1,2             1,2             1,2             1,2
0000220             1,2             1,2             1,2             1,2
0000240             1,2             1,2             1,2             1,2
0000260             1,2             1,2             1,2             1,2
0000300             1,2             1,2             1,2             1,2
0000320             1,2             1,2             1,2             1,2
0000340             1,2             1,2             1,2             1,2
0000360             1,2             1,2             1,2             1,2
0000400             1,2             1,2             1,2             1,2
0000420             1,2             1,2             1,2             1,2
0000440             1,2             1,2             1,2             1,2
0000460             1,2             1,2             1,2             1,2
0000500             1,2             1,2             1,2             1,2
0000520             1,2             1,2             1,2             1,2
0000540             1,2             1,2             1,2             1,2
0000560             1,2             1,2             1,2             1,2
0000600             1,2             1,2             1,2             1,2
```

But this is not true,it should be 1200.00,I have checked the code.

I am on Ubuntu 14.04.

Comment: What was the question?

Comment: @MarkSetchell How to print first 100 numbers in terminal knowing that it has 4 bytes?

Comment: `od -f` do you mean?

Comment: @MarkSetchell Look at the edit please!

Comment: The last output suggest numbers fifth to end are the same and od markes identical lines as * to avoid duplicates. If you don´t want to supress duplicates, use `od -f -v -N 14400 base.mod`

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't being facetious. As @mclead_ideafix implies, the asterisks mean that the data are repeated until offset 34100.

Comment: Try showing your code, please.

Comment: @MarkSetchell You were right,I have checked again!